# Loop to populate text in a different cell once it hits a character limit

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a set of input data and split them out of various cells once it hits a text limit

For example, the amount of characters in cell A1 is 100

I want to split it such that A1, B1, C1, D1 etc. all contains 10 character each

The input of the 100 characters is coming from a loop that combines entries of multiple cells together

I am able to write a loop that can combine the values into 1 cell
But I'm finding trouble to write it such that Cell A1 should only contain 10 characters before proceeding to Cell B1 to populate the next 10 characters etc.

```
Sub getReport()

Dim com As New cls_common_funct
Dim result, report, ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrw, length, count, i As Long
Dim exp, strategy As String
Dim firstFlag As Boolean

Set ws = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
Set result = Worksheets("result")
    result.Cells.ClearContents
lastrw = com.FindLastRow_WithinColumn(ws.Name, "A")
exp = ""
firstFlag = False

For i = 3 To lastrw
    strategy = ws.Cells(i, 1)
    If firstFlag = False Then
        exp = strategy
        firstFlag = True
    Else
        exp = exp & ", " & strategy
    End If
    
Next
result.Select
result.Range("A1") = exp
```

Comment: What about a formula instead of VBA `=MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)/10,,,10),10)`

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
Sub stringmanipulation()

Dim length As Long, count As Long, i As Long



length = Len(Range("A1")) 'gets length of range
 
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(length / 10, 0) - 1
 

For i = 1 To count
       Cells(1, i + 1) = Left(Range("A1"), 10)
       Range("A1") = Right(Range("A1"), length - 10)
       length = length - 10
Next i


Cells(1, i + 1) = Range("A1")
Range("A1").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! apologies but i realized i described the output incorrectly, instead of output into A1:A10, i actually meant A1, B1,C1,D1 etc.

Comment: I edited the code now it should be on columns, I used the cels(i,j) property.